# Find images in the above fold using Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to find images in the above fold using Puppeteer and set attribute `loading="eager"` to those images.

Here is what I've tried:

```js
const images = await page.$$("img");

images.forEach(async image => {
  if (await image.isIntersectingViewport()) {
    console.log("intersecting");
    image.setAttribute("loading", "eager");
  }
});
```

It finds the images in the above fold correctly. However, when I try to set the attribute to it, it throws an error: `TypeError: image.setAttribute is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

`image` is an `ElementHandle`, that means that it's an object on the puppeteer's world pointing to an element in the browser world.
If you want to set an attribute to the DOM element, you could call `evaluate` and set that in the browser.

```js
await image.evaluate(i => i.setAttribute("loading", "eager"));
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried it, but didn't work. Here is the code:
```images.forEach(async image => {
    if (await image.isIntersectingViewport()) {
      await image.evaluate(i => i.setAttribute("loading", "eager"));
    }
  });```

Comment: Added the await. What do you mean with didn't work? what happened?